# output raster is not being created

Tags: python, gdal

I created three functions the first open the raster file and test if it's correct or not. the second calculate a parameter and the third create my output raster file. the issue is that the output file is not being created. I'm stuck at this level please help me if you can.

```
    # -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np
import sys ,os
from osgeo.gdalconst import *

output_dir='C:\wamp\www\Données CRTS\irrisat_dessimination-smiej'
etp = os.path.join(output_dir,"L8_L8_ETpot_24_30m_2016_223.tif")
rain = os.path.join(output_dir,"GLDAS_NOAH025SUBP_3H.A2016223.sumday.rain.tif")
eff = os.path.join(output_dir,"eff_v11.tif")

class calculate_iwr :
    path=''
    def openRaster(self,raster):
        raster = gdal.Open(path)
        band=None
        if raster is None :
            print ("Erreur : Impossible d'ouvrir le raster: " )
        try :
            columns = raster.RasterXSize
            lines = raster.RasterYSize
            band = raster.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray(0,0,columns,lines)
        except:
            print ("Erreur : Impossible d'extraire la bande")
        return raster, band, columns, lines

    def parameters(self,parameter) :
        bands = []
        bands.append(self.band)
        if parameter == "IWR" :
            iwr=np.divide(np.subtract(bands[0]-bands[1]),bands[2])
        return iwr

    driver=gdal.GetDriverByName('GTIff')
    driver.Register()

    #std=np.std(NDVI)
    #mean=np.mean(NDVI)
    #new_image=driver.Create(dst_f, colonnes,lignes, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)
    #for canal in cannaux :
        #i=i+1
        #new_image.GetRasterBand(i).WriteArray(canal)
    #new_image.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(codeim)
    #new_image=None
    #histogramme (NDVI,std,mean)

    def createImage(new_image):

        new_image=driver.Create(path, self.columns,self.lines, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)
        new_image.SetProjection(projectionfrom)
        new_image.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)
        new_image.GetRasterBand(1).WriteRaster( 0, 0, columns, lines, output_dir )
        new_image=None
        return columns, lines

def main() :

    openRaster(etp)
    openRaster(rain)
    openRaster(eff)
    parameters("IWR")
    createImage(os.path.join(output_dir,"iwr.tif"))
```

Comment: could you show the error message? And first wild guess:  did you check what your `etp` variable holds? the error could be because of the "è" in the path

Comment: thanks for your quick answer. I have no error message and the etp holds the full path to a file

Comment: if you try to use `os.chdir(output_dir)` does it throw and error? In addition: your createImage function has an argument you are not using? Or do I miss something?

Comment: the os.chdir(output_dir) doesn't throw any error, and yes you're right the path argument wasn't used but I changed it to a constant string but still no output raster created.

Comment: i found out that the main function isn't executing the createImage() function